Pipelin Trivy [error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment type=JSON_RESULT;name=trivy0.002331999684293873.json;]
I am trying to scan image in Azure DevOps pipeline via Trivy tool,encountered following error:

2024-08-10T12:13:40Z    INFO    [misconfig] Misconfiguration scanning is enabled
2024-08-10T12:13:40Z    INFO    [secret] Secret scanning is enabled
2024-08-10T12:13:40Z    INFO    [secret] If your scanning is slow, please try '--scanners vuln' to disable secret scanning
2024-08-10T12:13:40Z    INFO    [secret] Please see also https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.54/docs/scanner/secret#recommendation for faster secret detection
2024-08-10T12:13:40Z    FATAL   Fatal error image scan error: scan error: unable to initialize a scanner: unable to initialize an image scanner: failed to parse the image name: could not parse reference: acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Failed: Trivy detected problems.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed: Trivy detected problems.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed: Trivy detected problems.
Publishing JSON results...
##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment type=JSON_RESULT;name=trivy0.002331999684293873.json;]/tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
##[error]Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file does not exist on disk.')
##[debug]System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file does not exist on disk.')
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskAddAttachmentCommand.AddAttachment(IExecutionContext context, Dictionary`2 eventProperties, String data) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/TaskCommandExtension.cs:line 355
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskAddAttachmentCommand.Execute(IExecutionContext context, Command command) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/TaskCommandExtension.cs:line 314
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.BaseWorkerCommandExtension.ProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, Command command) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/WorkerCommandManager.cs:line 217
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.WorkerCommandManager.TryProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String input) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/WorkerCommandManager.cs:line 148
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.addattachment type=JSON_RESULT;name=trivy0.002331999684293873.json;]/tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json
Done!
Finishing: Scan Docker image with Trivy


I have tryed to fix it according this article: https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy-azure-pipelines-task/issues/64
but still exist this error.
My pipeline code:
    
- stage: 'ScanImageVulnerability'
  displayName: 'Scan image vulnerability'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - job: ScanImage 
    displayName: 'Scan Image Job'
    steps:
      - task: trivy@1
        displayName: Scan Docker image with Trivy
        inputs:
          version: 'v0.54.1'
          loginDockerConfig: true
          ignoreUnfixed: true
          docker: false
          image: '$(acrServerName)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'

And the full Trivy stage log is:
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3511410Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Scan Docker image with Trivy'
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3512693Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3512891Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3513461Z ##[debug]=> True
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3513672Z ##[debug]Result: True
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3513907Z ##[section]Starting: Scan Docker image with Trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3518260Z ==============================================================================
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3518378Z Task         : Trivy: Take control of your application security
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3518638Z Description  : Trivy is the world’s most popular open source vulnerability and misconfiguration scanner. It is reliable, fast, extremely easy to use, and it works wherever you need it.
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3518895Z Version      : 1.5.1
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3518971Z Author       : Aqua Security
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3519032Z Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy-azure-pipelines-task)
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3519189Z ==============================================================================
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3586885Z ##[debug]Resource Utilization warnings is disabled, switch "DISABLE_RESOURCE_UTILIZATION_WARNINGS" variable to "true" if you want to enable it
2024-08-10T12:13:38.3812671Z ##[debug]Using node path: /home/guo/myagent/externals/node10/bin/node
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5116405Z ##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=/home/guo/myagent/_work/_temp
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5141645Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5143167Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_VERSION
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5155186Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DOCKER
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5157324Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DEBUG
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5158998Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_LOGINDOCKERCONFIG
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5160418Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_IMAGE
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5161852Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_IGNOREUNFIXED
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5163180Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_EXITCODE
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5164656Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DEVMODE
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5166108Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5167591Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5168987Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5175381Z ##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5176584Z ##[debug]loaded 12
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5183129Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5184296Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5185271Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5186108Z ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5193718Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5194801Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5195664Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5196711Z ##[debug]check path : /home/guo/myagent/_work/_tasks/trivy_8f9cb13f-f551-439c-83e4-fac6801c3fab/1.5.1/node_modules/azure-pipelines-tool-lib/lib.json
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5201140Z ##[debug]adding resource file: /home/guo/myagent/_work/_tasks/trivy_8f9cb13f-f551-439c-83e4-fac6801c3fab/1.5.1/node_modules/azure-pipelines-tool-lib/lib.json
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5202466Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5237222Z Preparing output location...
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5242174Z ##[debug]rm -rf /tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5261070Z ##[debug]path=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5261937Z ##[debug]image=acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5262713Z ##[debug]loginDockerConfig=true
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5263389Z ##[debug]ignoreUnfixed=true
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5264074Z ##[debug]severities=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5264732Z ##[debug]options=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5265352Z ##[debug]aquaKey=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5266023Z ##[debug]aquaSecret=undefined
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5266638Z ##[debug]docker=false
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5267459Z ##[debug]version=v0.54.1
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5268233Z Run requested using local Trivy binary...
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5270820Z Finding correct Trivy version to install...
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5273104Z Required Trivy version is v0.54.1
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5286966Z ##[debug]rm -rf /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5288749Z ##[debug]removing file
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5466198Z Downloading Trivy...
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5467036Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5468106Z ##[debug]testing directory '/tmp'
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5476793Z Downloading: https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/releases/download/v0.54.1/trivy_0.54.1_Linux-64bit.tar.gz
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5477858Z ##[debug]destination /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:38.5478585Z ##[debug]downloading
2024-08-10T12:13:38.6602429Z ##[debug]Content-Length of downloaded file: 39180445
2024-08-10T12:13:38.6603437Z ##[debug]creating stream
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9547868Z ##[debug]download complete
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9549996Z ##[debug]Downloaded file size: 39180445 bytes
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9550445Z Extracting Trivy...
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9552784Z Extracting archive
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9553932Z ##[debug]testing directory '/tmp/'
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9559050Z ##[debug]which 'tar'
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9565532Z ##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/tar'
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9566791Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/tar arg: ["xC","/tmp/","-f","/tmp/trivy"]
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9571076Z ##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/tar
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9571910Z ##[debug]arguments:
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9572544Z ##[debug]   xC
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9573140Z ##[debug]   /tmp/
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9574181Z ##[debug]   -f
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9574819Z ##[debug]   /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:38.9576769Z [command]/usr/bin/tar xC /tmp/ -f /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9351568Z ##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool '/usr/bin/tar'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9353033Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/tar'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9363114Z Setting permissions...
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9364165Z ##[debug]which 'chmod'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9366744Z ##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/chmod'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9367531Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/chmod arg: ["+x","/tmp/trivy"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9368292Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/chmod arg: ["+x","/tmp/trivy"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9369009Z ##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/chmod
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9369669Z ##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/chmod
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9370281Z ##[debug]arguments:
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9370894Z ##[debug]arguments:
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9371479Z ##[debug]   +x
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9372275Z ##[debug]   +x
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9372849Z ##[debug]   /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9373386Z ##[debug]   /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9373771Z [command]/usr/bin/chmod +x /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9436883Z ##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool '/usr/bin/chmod'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9439027Z ##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool '/usr/bin/chmod'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9439789Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/chmod'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9440460Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/chmod'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9441099Z ##[debug]which '/tmp/trivy'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9441828Z ##[debug]found: '/tmp/trivy'
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9442441Z ##[debug]debug=false
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9443810Z Configuring options for image scan...
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9446207Z ##[debug]exitCode=1
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9446979Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: ["image"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9447680Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: ["--exit-code","1"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9448337Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: ["--format","json"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9449049Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: ["--output","/tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9449842Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: ["--ignore-unfixed"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9450654Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: ["--scanners","vuln,misconfig,secret"]
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9451415Z ##[debug]/tmp/trivy arg: acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9451943Z Running Trivy...
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9452500Z ##[debug]exec tool: /tmp/trivy
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9453102Z ##[debug]arguments:
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9453680Z ##[debug]   image
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9455003Z ##[debug]   --exit-code
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9455589Z ##[debug]   1
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9456156Z ##[debug]   --format
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9456701Z ##[debug]   json
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9457279Z ##[debug]   --output
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9457917Z ##[debug]   /tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9458626Z ##[debug]   --ignore-unfixed
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9459239Z ##[debug]   --scanners
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9459863Z ##[debug]   vuln,misconfig,secret
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9461558Z ##[debug]   acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117
2024-08-10T12:13:39.9466393Z [command]/tmp/trivy image --exit-code 1 --format json --output /tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json --ignore-unfixed --scanners vuln,misconfig,secret acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6483980Z 2024-08-10T12:13:40Z   INFO    [vuln] Vulnerability scanning is enabled
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6485212Z 2024-08-10T12:13:40Z   INFO    [misconfig] Misconfiguration scanning is enabled
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6486243Z 2024-08-10T12:13:40Z   INFO    [secret] Secret scanning is enabled
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6488880Z 2024-08-10T12:13:40Z   INFO    [secret] If your scanning is slow, please try '--scanners vuln' to disable secret scanning
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6489949Z 2024-08-10T12:13:40Z   INFO    [secret] Please see also https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.54/docs/scanner/secret#recommendation for faster secret detection
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6491059Z 2024-08-10T12:13:40Z   FATAL   Fatal error image scan error: scan error: unable to initialize a scanner: unable to initialize an image scanner: failed to parse the image name: could not parse reference: acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6497511Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6546626Z ##[error]Failed: Trivy detected problems.
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6556701Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed: Trivy detected problems.
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6565700Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed: Trivy detected problems.
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6566246Z Publishing JSON results...
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6577173Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment type=JSON_RESULT;name=trivy0.002331999684293873.json;]/tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6588260Z ##[error]Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file does not exist on disk.')
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6598353Z ##[debug]System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file does not exist on disk.')
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskAddAttachmentCommand.AddAttachment(IExecutionContext context, Dictionary`2 eventProperties, String data) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/TaskCommandExtension.cs:line 355
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskAddAttachmentCommand.Execute(IExecutionContext context, Command command) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/TaskCommandExtension.cs:line 314
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.BaseWorkerCommandExtension.ProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, Command command) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/WorkerCommandManager.cs:line 217
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.WorkerCommandManager.TryProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String input) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/WorkerCommandManager.cs:line 148
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6600242Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.addattachment type=JSON_RESULT;name=trivy0.002331999684293873.json;]/tmp/trivy-results-0.32230546845629693.json
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6600552Z Done!
2024-08-10T12:13:40.6610039Z ##[section]Finishing: Scan Docker image with Trivy

The Pipeline work flow and acr screenshot:


Could somebody help to analyze this issue? THanks a ton.

I am not an expert for this kind of task, but when comparing the output [...] could not parse reference: acrguo.azurecr.io/imageName.guo:117 with your screenshot, one can spot the difference:

Your variable has a capital N, while the image name is with a lower n.
Try running it again with the correct image name or convert your variable to lowercase with lower.

Thanks for your help. You are right. The devil is in the details.I am so ashamed.

@Clair you are welcome, it is always the little details. If this solved your issue, please accept my answer so the rest of the community can benefit of it :) See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Yeah,learn new thing. I just know the 'useful' buttom,and now i learn the final status is should be click the 'accepted'  buttom. Thanks a lot. I will update my previous questions.
